# Solr+Nutch+AjaxSolr query

Tags: solr, nutch

1) I referred https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/reuters-tutorial for Ajax-Solr setup.

I want to know that although ajax-solr is running but it's searching under only reuters data. If I want to crawl the web using nutch and integrate it with solr,then i have to replace solr's schema.xml file with nutch's schema.xml file which will not be according to ajax-solr configuration. By replacing the schema.xml files, ajax-solr wont work(correct me if I am wrong)!!!

How would I now integrate Solr with Nutch along with Ajax-Solr so ajax-Solr can search other data on the web as well??

2) I would like to ask whether there are any front end API for Solr searching,except Ajax-Solr, which would help in efficient searching of the crawled web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look at Solr with multiple cores, it's better not to try mix documents with different nature in one collection
2. There are many APIs for SOLR, such as SOLRJ for Java (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj), SolPHP for PHP (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP) and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But would using Solr with multiple cores help solve my specified problem?

Comment: Yes. However, you will do 2 requests to different cores and then aggregate documents with different structure. Another way, if structures are not much different, you can integrate them into one common schema.xml (with implementing also adding some fields in custom Indexing plugin for Nutch, may be)

Comment: Ohh!!! Thanks for the information... That was really helpful!! Gonna give a shot at it.... Thanks..

Comment: I tried activating multiple cores but to no luck. I tried every single thing, every permutation and combination , but failed to set them up. <br> I followed these links [link1] (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) and [link2] (http://www.plaidpony.com/blog/post/2011/04/Multicore-SOLR-And-Tomcat-On-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx).... But they also didnt helped either. Can you please tell how to set them up???

Comment: Its been over 10-12 hours that I'm stuck with this. Kindly help. Thanks. Regards